# Remove NoData from ArcGIS Raster Dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to completely remove the NoData (pixel value 255) from a single band raster dataset. I don't want to make it transparent using symbology. Any ideas?

Comment: What value do you want instead?  If for example you wanted to convert NoData (255) to 123, you could use a raster calculator expression: `Con(IsNull("your_raster"), 123, "your_raster")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short you can't.  Raster data is a continuous grid, a perfect square or rectangle.  You can't poke holes in it.

The No Data is designed as a placeholder for areas where you have no data such as a mask or areas where there is actually no data.  Most software will transparent it out for you by default.  But as far as completely eliminating it from your dataset I don't think thats possible.